# i can focus before any number of pixel but if i want to focus any selective id before other number of pixel how i can do it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
<script type="text/javascript" >

window.addEventListener("hashchange", function () {
    window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, window.scrollY - 200);
});


</script>
```

```html
<li class="menu-item-has-children">
  <a href="#why_us_that_quick">Why Us</a>
</li>
<li class="menu-item-has-children">
  <a href="#our_mission_that_quick">Our Mission</a>
</li>
<li class="menu-item-has-children menu-item-mega-parent">
  <a href="#our_services_that_quick">services</a>
</li>
```

it is a general setting focus before x number of pixel but i want i selective anchor where id is our mission focus before different number of pixel